# Malware or exploit kit without escalation kit

Tags: malware, exploit, privilege-escalation

Does anyone know of any malware or exploit kit that do not use a privilege escalation kit and just do malicious things with an unprivileged permission?

Comment: Are you finding too many malware that escalates? What research have you done? What have you found? Metasploit has modules that do not escalate.

Comment: @schroeder Maybe the question is a little confusing. I am new to this field and I am looking for some malware examples that escalate and some do not. And I am wondering if there is a statistical ratio between these two kinds. Do you happen to know some materials that I can start with?

Comment: There are millions of malware samples, with 100's more showing up every day. I'm not sure what you're hoping to find. Is this a homework question?

Comment: @schroeder yep yep. It's a homework project. We are asked to analyze some malware samples.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably Google-dork Securelist's blog posts, as they give fairly detailed explanations of malware strains that they RE.

From there, see if they're on Contagiodump.